# Imacros saving extracted txt so csv file and adding new line for each word

Tags: imacros

I have a task to extract txt from website to csv file and save info in 1 line,
here is my code

Problem seems is because i'm using at the end of extract=txt\n, how i can make it in one line and keep same syntax as i'm using.

```
   for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    iimPlay("CODE:"
        + 'SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO\n'
        + 'TAG POS='+i+' TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"divtd textcenter vam" EXTRACT=TXT\n'
        + 'SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=trafficgoals.csv\n'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in the following way:

```
var M = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    M += 'TAG POS=' + i + ' TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"divtd textcenter vam" EXTRACT=TXT\n';
M += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.replace(/\\\\n/g, \'\');")\n'; 
M += 'SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=trafficgoals.csv\n';
iimPlayCode(M);
```

Comment: thanks but anyway have a problem that i extracting table with 6 lines, but in csv file i have 4 lines of information separated by comas and two of them are on line 2,3,. Do you know why is that happening? Here i have a screen http://clip2net.com/s/3sytrHf